# How to make a dynamic vertical table from an object using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have an object like this:

```
 var table = {
        name: 'Deficiency Information',
        columns: [cl1, cl2, cl3, cl4, cl5, cl6, cl7],
        row: ['cl1r1', 'cl2r1', 'cl3r1', 'cl4r1', 'cl5r1', 'cl6r1', 'cl7r1'],
        actions: ['edit', 'delete']
    };
```

I would like it to render as a table like this:

[image]

So basically, I have an object with a definition of columns, a single row of data and another row of actions that can be done with said data displayed as a vertical table.

What would be the simplest yet extensible way I can achieve this ?

Edit:

Based on romellem's pointer, I have added the following code:

```
 var buildTable = {
        header: function (header) {
            //     console.log(header);
            var _header = '<div class="demoHeader">' + header + '</div></th></tr><tbody>';
            return _header;
        },
        columns: function (columns) {
            var _cols
            for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                 _cols += '<td>';
                _cols += columns[i];
                 _cols += '</td>';
            }
               return _cols;
        },
        row: function (row) {
         var _row
            for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                _row += '<td>';
                _row += row[i];
                _row += '</td>';
            }
            return _row;
        },
        actions: function (action) {
            var _action
            for (var i = 0; i < action.length; i++) {
                _action += '<td>';
                _action += action[i];
                _action += '</td>';
            }
            return _action;
        }
    }

var _table = '<table class="demo"><tr class="demoHead"><th colspan="3">';
        Object.keys(table).forEach(function(element) {
            _table += ' <tr>';
            if (element.toString() === 'header') {
                _table += buildTable.header(table['header']);
            };
            if (element.toString() === 'columns') {
                _table += buildTable.columns(table['columns']);
            };
            if (element.toString() === 'row') {
                _table += buildTable.row(table['row']);
            };
            if (element.toString() === 'actions') {
                _table += buildTable.actions(table['actions']);
            };
            _table += '</tr>';
        });
        _table += '<tbody></table>';

   $('#dvTable').html(_table);
```

This is building a table but it is horizontally laid out instead of vertically, like I would like it to be. What can I do to change this to a vertical layout ?

I have a fiddle with this code as well [here : fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2u8vgLdd/1/)

Appreciate any help in advance.

Thanks

Comment: I'd use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate over my Object, then use [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over my arrays. While iterating, you can build an HTML string. Alternatively, you could use a templating library like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), so you'd pass in your object as-is and Handlebars takes care of the rest.

Comment: @romellem I appreciate your pointer, taking that route, I am able to build a table, however I am at my wits end on aligning it vertically.